# Minimum frame size in CSMA/CD

Tags: frame, bandwidth

May I ask, why the minimum frame size = bandwith * round trip time?
Why could it not be smaller than the bandwith * rtt?

Thenk you very much

Answer (score 0):

If the frame size is any smaller than bandwidth*RTT, the frame may have already been finished transmitting by the time the collision warning reaches the transmitting node, so the frame cannot be retransmitted. Hope that makes sense! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! So you mean the actual collision could or will still happen, but the transmitting node will "believe" that everything went ok/will be fine?

Comment: Exactly! Sorry for not replying, was offline for quite a while!